# "The view didn't return an HttpResponse object"

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is the error I am getting: `The view extraio.file_uploader.views.Upload_File didn't return an HttpResponse object.`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? I can't seem to figure out why I would be getting that exception since I am returning an HttpResponseRedirect.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import Files
from forms import Upload_File_Form

def Upload_File(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Upload_File_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in request.FILES.get_list('file'):
                f.save()
                orgfilename = Files(orgname=f.name)
                orgfilename.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('success.html')
        else:
            form = Upload_File_Form()
            return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You returning your `HttpResponse` object only on `POST` request.
Rewrite your view like this

```
def Upload_File(request):
    form = Upload_File_Form(request.POST or None,
                            request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
                f.save()
                orgfilename = Files(orgname=f.name)
                orgfilename.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('success.html')
   return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**EDIT**: BTW you forgot to set `context_instance` in you `render_to_response`
Also you can use `render` instead

```
render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

`request.FILES.get_list('file')` should be `request.FILES.getlist('file')`